# Block direct access to a file over but allow via http using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using below code to allow file download in my intranet asp.net web application. But one user hacked and found shared folder path of the file. How to restrict it?

```
System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
response.ClearContent();
response.Clear();
response.ContentType = "text/plain";
response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName + ";");
response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath("FileDownload.pdf"));
response.Flush();
response.End();
```

Comment: @HarisJayadaev What do you mean - direct access? You want to forbit it by explorer, but allow it by http?

Comment: Yes want to restrict using window explorer

Comment: adjust the folder security? But that's beyond the scope of SO (more superuser.com).

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it in IIS, using Directory Browsing option (IIS 7):

[image]

Or you can do it yourself by changing your [web.config](http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/directorybrowse) and adding the following options:

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I have already done it. But i don know how the user found physical file path and accessing it.

Comment: @HarisJayadev If it is dissabled he would not be able to access your folder. Perhaps he has the domain admin network priveledge, then he would be able to access anything he wants in your network.